# Spatial pie chart using geopandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pie-chart, geopandas

I am trying to make a pie chart that looks like the below [image]-

I am using geopandas for that-

```
us_states = gpd.read_file("conus_state.shp")
data = gpd.read_file("data_file.shp")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize= (10,10))
us_states.plot(color = "None", ax = ax)
data.plot(column = ["Column1","Column2"], ax= ax, kind = "pie",subplots=True)
```

This gives me the following error-

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\LSRATH~1.STU\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17992/1047905594.py in <module>
      1 fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize= (10,10))
      2 us_states.plot(color = "None", ax = ax)
----> 3 diff_env.plot(column = ["WS_MON1","WS_MON2"], ax= ax, kind = "pie")

c:\python38\lib\site-packages\geopandas\plotting.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    951         if kind in self._pandas_kinds:
    952             # Access pandas plots
--> 953             return PlotAccessor(data)(kind=kind, **kwargs)
    954         else:
    955             # raise error

c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    921             if isinstance(data, ABCDataFrame):
    922                 if y is None and kwargs.get("subplots") is False:
--> 923                     raise ValueError(
    924                         f"{kind} requires either y column or 'subplots=True'"
    925                     )

ValueError: pie requires either y column or 'subplots=True'
```

Even after specifying, subplots = True, it does not work.

How can I make a pie chart using 2 columns of the dataframe?

Below are the first five rows of the relevant columns-

```
diff_env[["Column1", "Column2", "geometry"]].head().to_dict()

{'Column1': {0: 2, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 12},
 'Column2': {0: 2, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 12},
 'geometry': {0: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x2c94e07f190>,
  1: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x2c94e07f130>,
  2: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x2c94e07f0d0>,
  3: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x2c94bb86d30>,
  4: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x2c94e07f310>}}
```

Comment: Can you hard-code the first 5 rows of the relevant columns `data` as a list of dictionaries ?

Comment: @PaulH, edit the question and added the first 5 rows.

Comment: can you include the geometry column?

Comment: @PaulH, added..

Comment: OK that didn't help -- we need to be able to copy/paste and create something that represents your data structure

Comment: @PaulH Here is a sample csv file- https://file.io/RJ3t2rUlcw4y

Comment: this isn't at all what "subplots" means. see the [pandas plotting docs](//pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/visualization.html?highlight=subplots#subplots) - passing the subplots kwarg cretes several distinct images - not mini charts on top of a single geography. you might get lucky and find someone willing to do the work of setting this complex plot up for you, but there's no geopandas tool that will just do this for you out of the box - you're just calling [pandas.DataFrame.plot.pie](//pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.pie.html) - no geometry info involved.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado do you mean it is not possible to produce such plot using geopandas or any other python library?

Comment: correct - not out of the box (at least, no library I know of). you'll have to construct the pie charts manually and place them on the map yourself. you can do this with matplotlib and geopandas, but there's no "make this plot" function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding pie chart at given coordinates to cartopy projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266955/adding-pie-chart-at-given-coordinates-to-cartopy-projection)

Comment: Well, I was hoping that geopandas would include such plots as they are available in ArcGIC. If it can plot spatial maps with points, then why not pie charts. I have posted this question on their github repo. Anyway, thanks for the link, I will look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- you have not provided any usable sample data.  Have randomly generated some
- this is inspired by [How to plot scatter pie chart using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56337732/how-to-plot-scatter-pie-chart-using-matplotlib)

#### sample data

|  | value0 | value1 | geometry | size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5 | 3 | POINT (-105.96116535117056 31.014979334448164) | 312 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | POINT (-79.70609244147155 36.46222924414716) | 439 |
| 2 | 4 | 7 | POINT (-68.89518006688962 37.84436728093645) | 363 |
| 3 | 7 | 9 | POINT (-118.12344177257525 31.909303946488293) | 303 |
| 4 | 2 | 7 | POINT (-102.1001252173913 28.57591221070234) | 326 |
| 5 | 3 | 3 | POINT (-96.88772103678929 47.76324025083612) | 522 |
| 6 | 5 | 8 | POINT (-112.33188157190635 48.16975143812709) | 487 |
| 7 | 7 | 6 | POINT (-95.15025297658862 44.59245298996656) | 594 |
| 8 | 3 | 1 | POINT (-100.36265715719063 46.787613401337794) | 421 |
| 9 | 2 | 4 | POINT (-81.82966451505015 35.161393444816056) | 401 |

#### full code

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import shapely
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

states = (
    gpd.read_file(
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvkelso/natural-earth-vector/master/geojson/ne_110m_admin_1_states_provinces.geojson"
    )
    .loc[lambda d: d["iso_3166_2"].ne("US-AK"), "geometry"]
    .exterior
)

# geodataframe of points where pies are to be plotted
n = 10
pies = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    geometry=[
        shapely.geometry.Point(xy)
        for xy in zip(
            np.random.choice(np.linspace(*states.total_bounds[[0, 2]], 300), n),
            np.random.choice(np.linspace(*states.total_bounds[[1, 3]], 300), n),
        )
    ],
    data={f"value{c}": np.random.randint(1, 10, n) for c in range(2)},
    crs=states.crs,
).pipe(lambda d: d.assign(size=np.random.randint(300, 600, n)))

# utility function inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56337732/how-to-plot-scatter-pie-chart-using-matplotlib
def draw_pie(dist, xpos, ypos, size, ax):
    # for incremental pie slices
    cumsum = np.cumsum(dist)
    cumsum = cumsum / cumsum[-1]
    pie = [0] + cumsum.tolist()

    colors = ["blue", "red", "yellow"]
    for i, (r1, r2) in enumerate(zip(pie[:-1], pie[1:])):
        angles = np.linspace(2 * np.pi * r1, 2 * np.pi * r2)
        x = [0] + np.cos(angles).tolist()
        y = [0] + np.sin(angles).tolist()

        xy = np.column_stack([x, y])
        ax.scatter([xpos], [ypos], marker=xy, s=size, color=colors[i], alpha=1)

    return ax


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax = states.plot(ax=ax, edgecolor="black", linewidth=0.5)
for _, r in pies.iterrows():
    ax = draw_pie([r.value0, r.value1], r.geometry.x, r.geometry.y, r["size"], ax)
```

#### output

[image]